# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource intermittently shown with S3

Tags: javascript, ajax, amazon-s3, cors

I have a function that `GET`s an image/video from an S3 bucket. When my app first loads, the function returns the image/video perfectly. But if I upload a new image/video and get a new signed URL to retrieve it, I get the following error (and the image/video fails to load):

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://s3-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/blah/blah' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I've set my S3 bucket's permissions to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

My code looks like this:

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
const media = document.createElement('img');

request.onprogress = (e) => {
  updateLoadingBar(e.percent);
};

request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
  if (request.readyState === 4) {
    media.src = URL.createObjectURL(request.response);
  }
};

request.responseType = 'blob';
request.open('get', url);
request.send();
```

A few quick notes:

1. The S3 signed URL is generated on my backend API using the same function every time.
2. If I have the Chrome dev tools open and `Disable cache` checked in the `Network` tab, it loads fine.

I'm grateful for any suggestions you may have to clear up this error. Thank you!

Comment: cool. What happens in an `incognito` or in another browser.. ?

Comment: @Panther `incognito` mode in Chrome: same error. Firefox (any mode): works perfectly every time. Safari: fails the same way as Chrome (except opening dev tools doesn't seem to help). Also important to note that I'm not using any browser extensions and the same errors happen when tested on another computer.

Comment: is your api and front end on the same domain? this happend to me when my DB was on a different domain to my site. have you tried this [amazon s3 cors](https://www.altcademy.com/questions/amazon-aws-s3-error-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling cache in the `XMLHttpRequest` allowed it to work:

```
request.open('get', url);
request.setRequestHeader('cache-control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
request.send();
```

If someone could explain why in the comments, I'd be extremely grateful :)

Comment: S3's CORS implementation is not entirely correct, and I suspect that your solution is not actually "correct" either, but may simply be injecting a header that causes Chrome to send a request that S3 handles correctly.  If I'm right, `request.setRequestHeader('cache-control', 'internet-cats, max-lives=9')` would have the same effect.